# Setting default value from another project/namespace

Tags: dxa, dxa-net

How do I set the default-module value in web config to be from another project/namespace? I tried setting the full name space into this value, but it does not seem to work.

Here is what I tried, but it did not work:

```
<add key="default-module" value="MyCoreModule"/>
```

Also this does not work

```
<add key="default-module" value="Custom.Project.Namespace.Areas.MyCoreModule"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “default module” is a logical Module/Area name, not a class name.

It is the name which is returned by your Module’s Area registration code (`AreaName` property). For example: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/master/webapp-net/Core/CoreAreaRegistration.cs